# Copy system lib files in python venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm trying to be really hacky and edit a system library file normally found inside `/usr/lib/python/` for a project I'm working on.

Obviously, I don't want to edit the actual file (and indeed I'd have to first make it `rw` as it's currently readonly).

Is there a way to tell python, when making a new virtualenv, to make copies of the existing system libraries and use those, so that I can safely edit them without breaking everything else that might be trying to use those files?

I've been creating the virtualenvs with

```
python3.7 -m venv myVenvName
```

Comment: There is no such feature in venv.

Comment: @wim is there any alternative tool that _will_ do that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Why not reinstall the same system python packages in the new venv?

Comment: Ideally, we use the `--relocatable` argument with `virtualenv` that we relocate virtualenv around.

Comment: If you want a stronger form of "virtual environment" that lets you change between sets of not just Python libraries but C libraries, external program dependencies, &c., you might consider [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/). (It's trivial to say "I want a Python interpreter with this specific patch applied used to run my program" in a Nix expression, so you can apply fixups not just to the standard library but the interpreter itself, or to its dependencies -- without changing the interpreter, or dependencies, used by the rest of the OS).